# Angular-google-maps panTo doesnt work

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular-google-maps

Hi so I've some angular/bootstrap code and trying to pan to position. I think that the problem is in different instances of GoogleMapsAPI Wrapper. Btw. zoom and print circle dont work too.

```
  constructor(private _service: MapService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private wrapper: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper) {
  }

  show(measurement: MeasurementDTO) {
    const latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(measurement.latLng.lat, measurement.latLng.lng());
    console.log(latlng.lat);
    this.map.panTo(latlng);
  }
```

And here part of view. Measurement comes from table but I think its useless info.

```
  <agm-map style="height: 600px" [latitude]="1" [longitude]="1" [usePanning]="true">
    <agm-marker-cluster [imagePath]="'https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/images/m'">
      <agm-marker
        *ngFor="let measurement of measurements"
        [latitude]="measurement.latLng.lat"
        [longitude]="measurement.latLng.lng">
      </agm-marker>
    </agm-marker-cluster>
  </agm-map>
        <button (click)="show(measurement)">Show</button>
```

**UPDATE 6.12.2018**

I figured it out by adding *map* in component:

```
  map: any;

  setMap(map) {
    console.log(map);
    this.map = map;
  }
```

And this onReady in html:

```
<agm-map #mapka style="height: 600px" [latitude]="52.279986" [longitude]="17.35229389999995" [usePanning]="true"
               (mapReady)="setMap($event)">
```